# Can FirebaseRecyclerAdapter be used with an Adpater class for clean code purposes?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, code-cleanup

Is it possible to work FirebaseRecyclerAdapter into an Adapter class?

Since with an MVVM structure, the point is to keep all business logic outside of the activity class.

Currently, FirebaseRecyclerAdpater/Options is hijacking the activity class.

Comment: Yes, not every time the MVVM architecture pattern solves the problem. In this case, you either create your own adapter and don't use the Firebase-UI library or you use the Firebase-UI library without MVVM.

Comment: Which would you suggest?
Because I would assume that the firebase adapter is efficient and solves many threading problems.

Comment: It depends on what you consider more important, the benefits of the library or the architecture pattern. If you are asking me, I prefer to have a simplified code and use the library.

Comment: @AlexMamo Would this be a good approach.
https://medium.com/android-news/android-architecture-components-with-firebase-907b7699f6a0
To use this method of monitoring firebase with LiveData and using the LiveData<List> in your adapter?

Comment: As I see the list (mEntities) is set directly into the adapter, which is correct, not the LiveData object. That approach looks good to me but The Firebase Database client already runs all network operations in a background thread. This means that all operations take place without blocking your main thread. Creating a new threads does not give any additional benefits.

Comment: But using this approach preserves the MVVM structure, allowing for cleaner code does it not? So you are keeping your work off the main thread and maintaining an easier working environment.

Comment: Yes, it does, for a cleaner architecture but not for keeping your work off the main thread. As I said, the Realtime Database, as well as Cloud Firestore client, already runs all network operations in a background thread.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Sorry, I must have understood your previous message incorrectly.

Comment: Hey Emmanuel. I've seen more interest in this topic, and many other users asking similar questions, so I think you might be interested in my answer from the following **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704121/need-help-in-implementing-viewmodel-class-with-cloud-firestore-backend/66706690#66706690)**.